# <enableEnhancedLookup>false</enableEnhancedLookup> on some environments

Tags: force.com, ide, search

Some developers when syncing with their server have this xml in the custom object, others have nothing (not true, just no tag). Anyone know what causes this.

When we go to:
Customize | Search | Search Settings

our objects dont have it checked.

Not sure what would cause sf.com ide to sync false in one case and nothing in the other.

Comment: The only workaround we have found is to set it, then sync, then unset and sync again, then we end up with false vs nothing... ugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless explicitly enabling/disabling the enhanced lookup preference, Salesforce doesn't set any value to the enhanced lookup preference to a custom entity object. And if a custom entity object doesn't have a value to it, it is omitted when retrieving the custom entity object through metadata API. So you will not see the enableEnhancedLookup field in the retrieved object's metadata file by default.

On the other hand, when deploying a custom entity object, Salesforce explicitly sets a boolean value to the enhanced lookup preference even if the enableEnhancedLookup field is not specified in the deploying object's metadata file. It has the custom entity object have a value of the enhanced lookup preference. That's why you see the enableEnhancedLookup field in the object's metadata file when you retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a bug, it should either be there or not, this sort of thing makes team development a nightmare.